# vs 2005 and .net 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, visual-studio-2005

Can i use vs 2005 and .net 3.5 framework together or can i use linq with vs 2005?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You need Visual Studio 2008 or later to target .NET 3.5.

Comment: @RoyiNamir As explained further in the comments, you can link to .NET 3.5 assemblies but you can't use the new syntax in your own code since the editor does not understand it.